# Why does increasing the hash table size for a chess engine, also drastically increase the time it takes to reach depth 30?

Tags: performance, hashtable, chess

I'm using the macOS app Stockfish which uses the current version of Stockfish 14.1 as the chess engine, and what surprises me is that it takes a lot less time for my computer (Apple M1 Pro 10C) to reach depth 30 when I set the hash table size to 1MB, compared to when I set it to say size 8GB.

Hash table of size 1MB takes ~18 s to reach depth 30 on initial chess position.
Hash table of size 8192MB takes ~85 s to reach depth 30 on initial chess position.

Does this mean that recomputation is faster than using memory?

Comment: I also added recommendation from the StockFish FAQ to my reply to you question. Thank you for the good question though!

Answer (score 1):

> Does this mean that recomputation is faster than using memory?

I'd guess (without knowing anything about Stockfish internals); that it means the hash table is too large to remain in the CPU's caches (making hash table access slow); and that the performance benefit of a larger hash table ("less collisions, shorter lists of things with the same hash") is dwarfed by performance cost (of more cache misses).

Comment: Great answer, thanks! You mention that in order have good performance, the hash table should fit inside the CPU's cache. M1 Pro has a L2 cache of 12MB, does this mean I can only use a maximum of 12MB hash table? Or am I just better off leaving the hash table size at 1MB?

Comment: @Vincent: The 12 MiB of L2 cache would be used for everything (not just the hash table). If you assume software has a loop that accesses (a piece of) the hash table, then uses 10 MiB of other memory (then goes back to the start of the loop to access a piece of the hash table again); then "too large to remain in the CPU's caches" would be "larger than 12 MiB minus the 10 MiB of other memory that's also being used" (or larger than 2 MiB).

Comment: Thank you for your observations. I've done some experiments and figured out that everything depends on an engine. Sometimes, larger cache produces faster results. See my reply below.

Answer (score 1):

A chess engine tries to allocate an approximate amount of time to reach a certain depth. Anyway, it only evaluates some possible moves to reach this depth. Therefore, with a larger cache, at a higher time spent, it usually evaluates a higher number of moves, thus producing better results. A larger cache is especially beneficial if you have a CPU with many threads and cores; a higher cache may produce results faster from a certain number of threads.

A larger cache size allows the engine to avoid calculating again the same positions caused by different moves. Therefore, it may take slower but produce higher quality results, i.e., the results will be different and better. The engine does not calculate all possible moves up to a given number of plies but tries to evaluate only the best moves. With a larger cache size, it will evaluate more moves up to the given search depth in plies. Therefore, you will get a higher "seldepth" value (selective search depth in plies) and more evaluated nodes, if not higher net nodes per second (NPS).

The optimal chess engine cache size does not correlate with the size of the RAM cache of the CPU. For a chess engine, it is faster to get the calculated results from RAM even with cache miss than to calculate the results of the same position again.

According to the [StockFish FAQ](https://github.com/official-stockfish/Stockfish/wiki/Stockfish-FAQ#hash),

> Set the hash to nearly the maximum amount of memory (RAM) available,
> leaving some memory free for other tasks. The Hash can be any value,
> not just powers of two. The value is specified in MiB, and typical
> consumer hardware will have GiB of RAM. For a system with 8GiB of RAM
> one could use 6000 as a reasonable value for the Hash.

According to a [StockFish Wiki article](https://github.com/official-stockfish/Stockfish/wiki/Useful-data#elo-cost-of-small-hash) that explains the cost of not having enough cache,

> The data suggests that keeping hashfull below 30% is best to maintain
> strength.

You can get the factual information yourself easily, by issuing the following commands to your UCI engine (assuming your CPU has 12 threads) with a 1 MB cache:

```
uci
setoption name Threads value 12
setoption name Hash value 1
setoption name UCI_AnalyseMode value true
go depth 30
```

On my computer, it gave the following results:

#### Depth: 30, Threads: 12, Cache: 1 MB

```
info depth 30 seldepth 28 multipv 1 score cp 36 nodes 77265471 nps 10348978 hashfull 1000 tbhits 0 time 7466 pv d2d4 g8f6 c2c4 e7e6 g1f3 d7d5 g2g3 c7c5 f1g2 c5d4 e1g1 f8e7 f3d4 e6e5 d4f3 e5e4 f3e5 b8c6 e5c6 b7c6
```

If I run the same commands, but the cache size is 32768 MB rather than 1 MB (`setoption name Hash value 32768`), I get the following results:

#### Depth: 30, Threads: 12, Cache: 32768 MB (32 GB)

```
info depth 30 seldepth 42 multipv 1 score cp 24 nodes 105154983 nps 12110443 hashfull 22 tbhits 0 time 8683 pv d2d4 d7d5 g1f3 g8f6 c2c4 d5c4 e2e3 e7e6 f1c4 c7c5 e1g1 a7a6 d4c5 f8c5 d1d8 e8d8 c4e2 d8e7 b1d2 c8d7 d2b3 c5d6 b3a5 b7b6 a5c4 d7b5 f1d1 b5c4 e2c4 h8c8 c4e2 b8c6 c1d2
bestmove d2d4 ponder d7d5
```

As you see, with the larger cache, the engine evaluated the higher number of nodes and higher NPS and higher "seldepth". The final moves that the engine recommended also differ, starting from the 2nd ply (d7d5 vs g8f6). Thus, at 12 threads and a depth of 30, a large enough cache caused NPS to increase by 15%, the number of evaluated nodes increased by 27%, but the overall time increased by 14%.

The value after "hashfull" means the fullness of the cache space in tens of percentage points, i.e., "hashfull 1000" mean 100.0%; "hashfull 22" mean 2.2%.

With even bigger number of threads (96) and higher depth (45), the difference is even more pronounced. Although it evaluated just 6% more nodes, it achieved 22% NPS increase and 20% time decrease. So, while your observations were based on a CPU with a low number of threads (8), on a Xeon CPU with higher number of threads (96) it took faster to evaluate the position. Here are the results:

#### Depth: 45, Threads: 96, Cache: 1 MB

```
info depth 45 seldepth 31 multipv 1 score cp 22 nodes 7744802440 nps 49384683 hashfull 1000 tbhits 0 time 156826 pv e2e4 e7e5 g1f3 b8c6 f1c4 f8c5 d2d3 d7d6 c2c3 g8f6 b1d2 e8g8 e1g1 a7a6 c4b3 h7h6 f1e1 f8e8 h2h3 c8e6 d2c4 b7b5 c4e3 e6b3 d1b3 c5e3 c1e3
bestmove e2e4 ponder e7e5
```

#### Depth: 45, Threads: 96, Cache: 327680 MB (320 GB)

```
info depth 45 seldepth 57 multipv 1 score cp 18 nodes 8238379798 nps 63446824 hashfull 143 tbhits 0 time 129847 pv e2e4 e7e5 g1f3 b8c6 f1b5 g8f6 e1g1 f6e4 f1e1 e4d6 f3e5 c6e5 e1e5 f8e7 b5f1 e8g8 d2d4 e7f6 e5e1 f8e8 c2c3 e8e1 d1e1 d6e8 c1f4 d7d5 b1d2 c8f5 e1e3 e8d6 a2a4 a7a5 f1d3 f5d3 e3d3 c7c6 a1e1 g7g6 h2h3 h7h5 e1e2 f6g7
bestmove e2e4 ponder e7e5
```

Therefore, I would recommend setting the cache space size as high as your available RAM allows (but not letting the memory swap).

If I set the limit by time rather than by the number of plies (such as "go movetime 3600000" to let the evaluation take one hour), on a CPU with 12 threads and 32 GB cache, it takes about 10 minutes to fill the cache space entirely, but even at one-hour calculations, higher cache size produces better results.

Answer (score 0):

I would just like to add the differentiation between MB and MiB, since both are used quite interchangeably across the web, which left me a bit confused:

"MiB" stands for Mebibyte, a unit of digital information storage. It is closely related to the Megabyte (MB), which is more commonly known in everyday digital usage. However, there's a key difference in how they are defined:

**Megabyte (MB):** Traditionally, a Megabyte was defined as
10^6 bytes (or 1,000,000 bytes) in the decimal system. This definition is commonly used in contexts like storage media (hard drives, SSDs, etc.). However, in some computing contexts, a Megabyte has been used to refer to
2^20 bytes (or 1,048,576 bytes), which can create ambiguity.

**Mebibyte (MiB):** To resolve this ambiguity, the Mebibyte was defined specifically as
2^20 bytes, which is exactly 1,048,576 bytes. This is part of the binary system of measurement, which is more aligned with the binary nature of computing.

This is important for precision, especially in computing and programming contexts, where memory is typically addressed in powers of two.